# Notation for sets A, B not subset of each other

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Given two sets $A, B$, is there a notation for $A \not\subseteq B \:\land\: A \not\supseteq B$?

That is, $A, B$ are not necessarily disjoint, but are distinct in such a way that neither is a subset of the other.

Comment: I don't know if there is a particular symbol but since the subset relation is a partial order you can just say that $A$ and $B$ are incomparable (with respect to $\subseteq$)

Comment: Not that I know of ... but it would be handy to have a simple single symbol for this, I agree!

Comment: To @aldodecristo's point ... Wikipedia's ["Comparability" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability) mentions that incomparability with respect to "$<$" is sometimes written (more or less) as $$\not\underset{>}{\overset{<}{=}}$$ (that is, `\not\underset{>}{\overset{<}{=}}`). Perhaps the (*ahem*) comparable set-theoretic symbol is $$\not\underset{\supset}{\overset{\subset}{=}}$$ (that is, `\not\underset{\supset}{\overset{\subset}{=}}`).

Comment: Sure, you could do TeX tricks like $A\mathrel{^\nsubseteq_\nsupseteq}B$, but it is not common.

Comment: I guess it's unambiguous enough, albeit somewhat impractical. A better option would be to place the symbols side-by-side, like so: $A \not\supseteq \not\subseteq B$, except with only one strike across both of them.

Comment: In the context of a partial order $\langle P,\le\rangle$ one sometimes sees the notation $x\|y$ used to mean that $x\not\le y$ and $y\not\le x$. I would not use this unless you really are thinking of $\subseteq$ specifically as a partial order, and then only after defining it. In the overwhelming majority of contexts I agree with Martin Väth’s answer.

Answer (score 3):

No. $A\setminus B\ne\emptyset\ne B\setminus A$ is sufficiently short and clear.